# Family database prolog query

Tags: prolog, logic

I am using the below family database to practice prolog. I want to...

'Find the first name and surname of mothers whose children’s combined incomes are 
greater than £140,000, where at least one child is unemployed. The rule should also return 
the first name of the unemployed child/children, and the value of the children’s combined 
incomes'

so far I have this code...Help would be appreciated, really struggling on this exercise. thanks :)

```
(Fname,Sname,Income):- 
family(person(_,_,_,_),person(Fname,Sname,_,_),Children),
total(Children,Income),
Income > 140000.
```

.

```
total([Person|List],Sum):-
salary(Person,S),   % S: salary of the first person
total(List,Rest),   % Rest: sum of salaries of others
Sum is S + Rest.
```

.

```
family(
person(pat,marx,date(10,march,1944),unemployed),
person(charlotte,marx,date(11,february,1946),unemployed),
[
    person(aine,marx,date(17,april,1985),unemployed),
    person(louis,marx,date(25,june,1980),works(harriott,32000)),
    person(pearl,marx,date(10,june,1981),unemployed),
    person(pat_jr,marx,date(11,march,1983),works(world_of_food,850000)),
    person(ricky,marx,date(18,february,1987),unemployed)
]
).

family(
person(fred,chomsky,date(3,october,1955),works(bean_counters,100000)),
person(sarah,chomsky,date(19,october,1961),works(supercomms, 60000)),
[   
person(amos,chomsky,date(1,july,1984),works(sell_cell, 80000))
]
).

family(
person(ted,marx,date(10,july,1948),unemployed),
person(adelheid,marx,date(9,december,1948),unemployed),
[   person(ted_jr,marx,date(14,april,1988),works(world_of_food,90000)),
    person(jenny,marx,date(23,may,1984),unemployed),
    person(margaret,marx,date(23,may,1984),unemployed),
    person(sadie,marx,date(23,may,1984),unemployed),
    person(louis,marx,date(22,august,1979),unemployed),
    person(alan,marx,date(9,may,1990),unemployed)
]
```

).

```
family(
person(ted,russell,date(21,may,1938),retired),
person(victoria,russell,date(9,november,1944),retired),
[   person(betty,russell,date(18,august,1971),works(boat_house,65000)),
    person(jack,russell,date(27,may,1965),works(green_machine,15000)),
    person(joan,russell,date(9,april,1963),works(green_machine,15000)),
    person(penelope,russell,date(9,april,1963),works(green_machine,15000)),
    person(enda,russell,date(2,november,1968),works(exc-u-vate,15000)),
    person(amos,russell,date(27,may,1965),works(green_machine,15000)),
    person(algernon,russell,date(2,november,1968),works(exc-u-vate,15000)),
    person(cal,russell,date(9,october,1970),works(sell_cell,30000))
]
```

).

```
family(
person(bill,kant,date(7,august,1942),works(fibrefast,100000)),
person(ann,kant,date(9,october,1945),works(roulada,100000)),
[   person(mark,kant,date(25,april,1970),works(harriott,36000)),
    person(cal,kant,date(22,december,1966),works(harriott,35000)),
    person(simon,kant,date(27,january,1965),works(harriott,31000)),
    person(sol,kant,date(17,november,1964),unemployed),
    person(andrew,kant,date(9,march,1968),works(harriott,32000)),
    person(joan,kant,date(27,january,1965),works(harriott,34000))
]
```

).

```
family(
person(ted,russell,date(6,june,1950),works(mopper-ups,25000)),
person(helen,russell,date(10,june,1951),works(harriott,110000)),
[   person(maura,russell,date(21,february,1972),works(sparrow_hotel,19000)),
    person(simon,russell,date(24,december,1970),works(zoom-away,50000)),
    person(victoria,russell,date(23,january,1971),works(volts,49000)),
    person(andrew,russell,date(24,june,1969),works(sparrow_hotel,35000)),
    person(cal,russell,date(15,april,1974),works(sparrow_hotel,55000)),
    person(milly,russell,date(21,february,1972),works(sparrow_hotel,19000))
]
```

).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very odd database layout, but that doesn't need to stop us. First the head of the rule with the things we're going to return:

```
q(MotherFirst, MotherLast, UnemployedKids, CombinedIncome) :-
```

We're considering families here, so let's match them and pull out the mother's info:

```
    family(_, person(MotherFirst, MotherLast, _, _), Children),
```

The underscores there correspond to the father, the mother's date-of-birth and occupation. None of those are relevant to the problem so forget 'em. Next we need to do some processing on the kids: we need to find the ones that are unemployed and get the combined income. I will do two traversals because it's simpler for me. First the sum of their income:

```
    total_income(Children, CombinedIncome),
    CombinedIncome > 140000,
    unemployed(Children, UnemployedKids),
    UnemployedKids = [_|_]. % ensure we have at least one unemployed kid
```

I've broken the task down a little bit; let's go ahead and write some helpers:

```
% compute the total income for a list of people
total_income([], 0).
total_income([person(_, _, _, works(_, Amount) | People], Total) :- 
    total_income(People, Subtotal),
    Total is Subtotal + Amount.

% find the unemployed people in a list of people
unemployed([], []).
unemployed([person(FN, LN, DOB, unemployed) | People], 
           [FN | Unemployed]) :-
    !, % cut so that we don't enter the next rule with someone who is unemployed
    unemployed(People, Unemployed).
unemployed([_|People], Unemployed) :- unemployed(People, Unemployed).
```

Both of those could be simplified considerably using [library(aggregate)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate) or even some folds (perhaps with [library(lambda)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/file_details/lambda/prolog/lambda.pl) but this is a straightforward "classic" (wordy) solution.

Comment: Hey great answer! is it possible to not return Values when there are not unemployed kids? When I run this in prolog I am returning an empty list, instead if there are no unemployed kids, nothing should be returned. I will play about with it now, but feel free to answer if you beat me to the punch :) Also I would just like to return the unemployed childs first name, not all his details, thanks!

Comment: I added more familys which may help

Comment: And out of curiousity, is it possible to do this without recursion?

Comment: @user3904388 I think you'll find it's pretty easy to make the code respect your other changes. In my rush to answer I seem to have missed them but I think you ought to be able to figure it out. As for recursion, there may be ways of avoiding explicit recursion with metapredicates (maplist, fold, etc.) it will still be happening in the background somewhere because that is the only way to repeat in Prolog.

Comment: @user3904388 I've made the changes anyway. :)

Comment: Thank you :) i figured it out in a non recursive way as well, but thus is great!